# Realm - offline use

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

I am creating an app which downloads data from a particular source and stores them in a Realm database. According to my understanding, I should be able to access that database every time, I need that data, after that.

So I tried following process: Initialize the database. Download data and fetch database that data. Print data on terminal. -> As far as this, everything is going well.

So now according to my understanding, I closed the app and restarted it. Now I tried to print out the data, but there was no reaction. Does that mean, that the database is just alive for the period, in which my app is active?

Is there a way to store a Realm database on an android device for offline use? That means, in case that my user has no access to the internet and needs to use the downloaded database.

My Code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final MainActivity act = this;
        initRealm();
        setRights();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Button for updating database
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.getData);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Connects to database
                ConnectToDatabase c = new ConnectToDatabase(act);
                c.doInBackground();
                values = c.getValues();

                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                realm.beginTransaction();
                int i = 0;
                for (List<Object> rows : values) {
                    entry e = realm.createObject(entry.class, String.valueOf((++i) + 1));
                    //e.setEntry();
                    e.setNachname((String) rows.get(1));
                }
                realm.commitTransaction();
                realm.close();
                //showResults();
            }
        });
        Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.qr_scanner);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    showResults();
                }
        });
}



    //Show current Realm results
    public void showResults(){
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmQuery<entry> query = realm.where(entry.class);
        RealmResults<entry> listEntries = query.findAll();
        for (entry x : listEntries){
            System.out.println(x.getId());
        }
        realm.close();
    }

    //Initialisation for Realm
    private void initRealm() {
        Realm.init(this);
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("management.database")
                .directory(new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/realm/"))
                .build();
        Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
    }


    private void setRights() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

Comment: You should remove `setRights();` it is just hiding bugs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `initRealm()` method, you include the following command:

```
Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);
```

In a nutshell, you delete your realm everytime you initialize it. This is why you get no results back. You don't need an internet connection to access your Realm. It is stored locally. You should just avoid deleting it.

Comment: Thanks! I feel so dumb. I misinterpreted this function. I thought, this would just remove the defaultConfiguration and replace it with mine.

Comment: No worries. Glad i could help. Enjoy coding!

Comment: May I ask another question? What happens if I want to download data again and fetch that database with updated values? Will this database have double entries? Normally databases don't have duplicate entries.

Comment: Should I rather delete the database and replace it with a new one or just add new Objects to it?

Comment: Supposing you get your data in json format, there is this wonderful realm method that will create a new "table" if there is none, or update the existing one: `createOrUpdateAllFromJson(YourTable.class,YourJSON)`

Comment: Look it up at the official realm documentation for Java.
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/